# Hide a base class method in a generic derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, method-hiding

I have a base class like this:

```
class FooBase
{
    public bool Do(int p) { /* Return stuff. */ }
}
```

And a child class like this:

```
class Foo<T> : FooBase
{
    private Dictionary<T, int> Dictionary;

    public bool Do(T p)
    {
        int param;
        if (!Dictionary.TryGetValue(p, out param))
            return false;
        return base.Do(param);
    }
}
```

If the user creates a `Foo<string>` object called "fooString", then he can call both `fooString.Do(5)` and `fooString.Do("test")` but if he creates a `Foo<int>` object called "fooInt", he can only call the Do method of the derived class. I prefer the second no matter what the `T` is.

The Do methods in both of these classes essentially do the same thing. The one in the derived class gets an integer from a `Dictionary<T, int>` using the given parameter and calls the Do method of the base class using it.

That's why I want to hide the Do method of the `FooBase` in `Foo<T>`. How can I achieve this or something similar? Any design advice to overcome this would also be nice.

Comment: Have you considered making the Do of the base class protected?

Comment: @Hammerstein - Yes, but I need it to be public. The base class is not abstract and the Do method is it's main function so it has to be public.

Comment: If they do the same thing, what do you gain from hiding the base method? It shouldn't make a difference if the other variant was called, since they do the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but if he creates a `Foo<int>` object called "fooInt", he can only call the Do method of the derived class.

No, that's not true. If the declared type of the variable is `FooBase`, it will still call the `FooBase` method. You're not really preventing access to `FooBase.Do` - you're just hiding it.

```
FooBase foo = new Foo<int>();
foo.Do(5); // This will still call FooBase.Do
```

Full sample code to show that:

```
using System;

class FooBase
{
    public bool Do(int p) { return false; }
}

class Foo<T> : FooBase
{
    public bool Do(T p) { return true; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        FooBase foo1 = new Foo<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(foo1.Do(10)); // False

        Foo<int> foo2 = new Foo<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Do(10)); // True
    }
}
```

> That's why I want to hide the Do method of the FooBase in Foo.

You need to think about [Liskov's Substitutability Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

*Either* `Foo<T>` shouldn't derive from `FooBase` (use composition instead of inheritance) *or* `FooBase.Do` shouldn't be visible (e.g. make it protected).

Comment: It is true, it calls the Do method of the derived.

Comment: @d4wn: No, it will call the Do method of the base class, I'm sure. I'll verify it right now, but I'm really pretty sure...

Comment: @d4wn: I've edited my answer to show a short but complete program proving it calls the Do method of the base class when the variable is of type `FooBase`.

Comment: Both are true actually. For a `Foo<int>` instance, if the variable is declared as `FooBase`, the _base_ method will be called. If it's declared as `Foo<int>`, the method of the derived class will be called.

Comment: @ken2k you're right. Well, it's allright if someone using an istance of FooBase. What I'm after is like using the "new" keyword to hide methods but I can't use it since the method in the derived class is generic.

Comment: @ken2k: The claim I was saying was untrue was "but if he creates a `Foo<int>` object called "fooInt", he can only call the Do method of the derived class".

Comment: @d4wn: But you *shouldn't* use the "new" keyword to hide methods in general. If a method shouldn't be called, it shouldn't be accessible. Hiding methods should be a last resort for reasons of backward compatibility etc.

Comment: Yes, now it seems like it was a design mistake. I didn't mind the fact that it was accessible because it wasn't a problem. If a user can get the integer, he should be able to call the method that's in the base class I thought. I wanted to hide it because someone that creates a Foo<T> object would most likely not "need" to call the Do method of the base class. Now it seems wrong. Since the both methods should be accessible and (thanks to generics) they both can have the same signature, the way to go is renaming the Do method of the derived class.

Comment: I don't think `new` is only for backwards compatibility. I typically use it to work around the lack of result type co-variance in C#. So the derived class hides an equivalent method from the base class, but has a more specific result type.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes, that's another time to use it. That comes into the "etc" in my earlier comment, which I realize wasn't very specific :) The main point is that method hiding shouldn't be used as a way to *prevent* access to the hidden method; it should be used as a way to encourage/allow access to another method.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a base class that is abstract with a `protected Do` method, and rewrite your current `FooBase` class to inherit from `Foo<T>`:

```
public abstract class FooBaseAbstract
{
    protected bool Do(int p)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// You can use this one just as your current FooBase class
public class FooBase : Foo<int>
{
}

public class Foo<T> : FooBaseAbstract
{
    public bool Do(T p)
    {
        if (true /* some test here */)
        {
            return base.Do(4);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

(of course change the class names)